# Loop xpath pentaho Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am using get data from xml step to loop (by xpath) on all fields in a file xml but the loop continue to all next steps in the transformation, I want to know how can i stop loop after executing all rows of my xml file?
PS: I am using Kettle 6.1

Comment: Could you show us the input you're using, the output you're getting and the output you want?

Comment: Do you mean "Get data from XML" step is still running even after the next step has started? Could you post the log you're getting?